# Does DJI Mini [2] have the same geofencing as other DJI drones?

Tags: regulations, dji, dji-mavic-mini, dji-mini-2

DJI is infamous for its overzealous geofencing. This feature prevents or seriously hinders operation, sometimes in areas where there are no legal restrictions.

Now, in most jurisdictions, sub-250g drones have fewer restrictions, if any. For example, in Australia, the 5 km exclusion zone around airports does not apply to such drones.

Does DJI still apply the same geofencing rules to their Mini series as for their larger drones? I couldn't find a clear statement anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

DJI publish their geo-fenced areas on their website: https://www.dji.com/uk/flysafe/geo-map

You can select your area and model at the top of the page; a quick check suggests the Mini currently has similar restrictions to their larger drones in Australia, but you should be able to check your intended location. Note that only the red areas on that map prohibit flying; most other zones can be user-unlocked.

Comment: I should have mentioned: yes, I've seen this map, and I've noticed it doesn't depend on the model at all, despite the selection. This is either an omission or, how should I put it, sabotage. In Australia (and I presume in many other places) Mini would be legal to fly even in (parts of) the red zones (within reason). I'd really like a confirmation from someone who owns it, but it seems that with DJI an investment into an NFZ hack should be budgeted in from the beginning...

Comment: I have noticed some differences between models on that map in the past, but this has largely been the shape of a zone rather than a location (for example, Inspire vs Inspire 2 - I assume older models only supported circular NFZs.) However, whether the unlocking implementation is different with the smaller models I don't know so hopefully someone else can answer that for you.